# PrimeNG ToggleButton icon

Tags: html, angular5, font-awesome, primeng, togglebutton

I am trying to add an icon from Font-awesome to my ToggleButton

```
<p-toggleButton [(ngModel)]="checked" (onChange)="doThis"
        aria-hidden="true">
    <i class="fa fa-shield"></i> </p-toggleButton>
```

Is it only by pButton possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize a `toggleButton` with *onIcon* and *offIcon* properties :

```
<p-toggleButton [(ngModel)]="checked" onLabel="I confirm" offLabel="I reject" onIcon="fa fa-check" offIcon="fa fa-times"
 [style]="{'width':'150px'}"></p-toggleButton>
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-izgb41)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i wanted